Tests Are Missing on Master Node in pytest-xdist Distributed Testing
I'm using pytest-xdist to run tests in a distributed fashion across multiple worker nodes. While the tests are correctly discovered and executed on the worker nodes, it appears that the master node is not recognizing or displaying these tests. Instead, I receive an Empty Suite message on the master node, even though tests are running on the workers.
Command Used:
pytest -n 2 --dist=loadfile --alluredir=allure_results tests --env=prod --platform=ios

PyTest hooks:
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items, config):
    try:
        platform = config.option.platform.lower()

        simple_test_name = 'test_simple'
        simple_test = next((item for item in items if item.name == simple_test_name), None)

        if simple_test:
            config.simple_test = simple_test

        mark_to_remove = "only_ios" if platform == "android" else "only_android"

        filtered_items = []
        for item in items:
            item_marks = [mark.name for mark in item.own_markers]
            if mark_to_remove not in item_marks:
                filtered_items.append(item)
        items[:] = filtered_items
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warning(f'Error: {e}')


def pytest_collection_finish(session):
    try:
        if not session.items:
            simple_test = getattr(session.config, 'simple_test', None)

            mark_flag = session.config.option.markexpr

            if not simple_test:

                @allure.title('Dummy test')
                def test_default():
                    assert True

                test_default = pytest.Function.from_parent(session, name='test_default', callobj=test_default)
                test_default.add_marker(pytest.mark.__getattr__(mark_flag))

                session.items.append(test_default)
            else:
                simple_test.add_marker(pytest.mark.__getattr__(mark_flag))
                session.config.option.markexpr = ''
                session.items.append(simple_test)
        logger.info(f'Tests to run: {session.items}')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warning(f'Error: {e}')

pytest_sessionfinish is observed to be called twice: first with exit status 0 and then with exit status 5, indicating an Empty Suite.
Why is the master node reporting an Empty Suite while the worker nodes are successfully executing tests?
How can I ensure that tests collected and executed on the worker nodes are also visible and accounted for on the master node?
Are there specific settings or options in pytest-xdist that need to be configured to properly aggregate and display test results on the master node?
